# Make specific App into widget?

Tags: samsung, app-widgets

I apologize if this has been asked and answered, if it has please just link me to the solution.

Here's the question:

Is there a way to make a section of a specific app into a widget if the app itself does not come with it's own?  I'm asking for my [Venstar Skyport thermostat app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.venstar.skyport&hl=en), which allows me to control the temperature of my home via my Android.  It would be extremely awesome if there was a way for me to turn the temperature controls into a widget so I could operate it without opening the app every time we want to change it.

Thanks a lot!

**Device:**

- Samsung Galaxy S7
- Android 6.0.1
- Kernel 3.18.20
- Not Rooted (But if it
  will help, I'd figure out how to do so)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking, can one directly reach the temperature controls without logging into the app, the answer is **no**.

Since the app doesn't have *activities* that can be pulled and placed as widgets. Some apps have, some don't. [Quick Shortcut maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) is one such app that can reveal activities and place them as shortcuts for quick access. I installed the app in question and it doesn't have any activities, except the main log in
- you will need to search for an app that works and can show activities for you to place as shortcuts, which can be directly accessed or used by [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) apps